# Valid Proof for Cayley Hamilton Theorem? (Not the usual incorrect one)

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, alternative-proof

By induction; case n=1 is true.

$A$ admits an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with eigenvector $v$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Change $A$ into a basis $e_1=v,...,e_n$. Then $\exists X$ such that $XAX^{-1}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\lambda & * \\ 0 & B \\ \end{array} \right)$ where $C_A(x)=(x-\lambda)C_B(x)$ $[1]$

$\Rightarrow A=X^{-1}\left( \begin{array}{ccc}\lambda & * \\ 0 & B \\ \end{array} \right)X$ so $C_A(A)=C_A\left[X^{-1}\left( \begin{array}{ccc}\lambda & * \\ 0 & B \\ \end{array} \right)X \right]=X^{-1}C_A\left[\left( \begin{array}{ccc}\lambda & * \\ 0 & B \\ \end{array} \right)\right]X$

Then using $[1]$ we get:
$C_A(A)=X^{-1}\left[\left( \begin{array}{ccc}\lambda-\lambda & * \\ 0 & B-\lambda \\ \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{ccc}C_B(\lambda) & * \\ 0 & C_B(B) \\ \end{array} \right)\right]X$ then by the inductive step we have $C_B(B)=0$ so we achieve
$C_A(A)=X^{-1}\left[ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}0 & * \\ 0 & B-\lambda \\ \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{ccc}C_B(\lambda) & * \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{array} \right)\right]X=0$

Thanks.

Comment: What is "the usual incorrect one"?

Comment: $C_A(x)=det(A-xI)$ so $C_A(A)=det(A-AI)=det(0)=0$ ?

Comment: Ah, understood.

Comment: @marc LOL, good one

Comment: @marc Although, it can be made right by some use of commutative algebra over $K[f]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be correct.  You assume that the field is $\mathbb C$.
But when the field is any algebraically closed field, there is an
even easier argument using essentially the same induction: first
prove using induction starting with the existence of an eigenvalue
that the matrix is similar to a triangular matrix; then note that
Cayley-Hamilton is obvious for triangular matrices.

This special case implies the general case by abstract nonsense.

Comment: Yes, this sort of proof does appear in some texts and is correct, and is how I first learned the Cayley Hamilton ( for the complex  case). I never really liked the specialization of $x$ to $A$, even though it can be justified rigorously.